# Python Tkinter Grid Manager is Ignoring Sizing of Previous Items and Wrapping Frames

Tags: python, for-loop, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-layout

[image][image]

I was thinking the Grid manager was pretty straightforward, but I'm stuck. I basically have three frames, starting from the main window and each frame using the previous as its master.

I'm trying to create 12 blocks inside the second frame, but when I try to create the blocks it wraps around its master frame and adds extra space at the end.

I also don't understand why I can change the hScroll width to also change the size of its master frame, example being set to 1000, but changing the width of its master frame, even increasing size does nothing.

I'm trying to learn how to use Tkinter and am looking for where I am messing up conceptually here, not so much just a code fix.

```
# Main frame
worksheetFrame = tk.Frame(tkRoot, width=2000, height=800, background='BLUE')
worksheetFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(100, 0), pady=(60, 0))

# Horizontal scrollbar
hScroll = tk.Frame(worksheetFrame, width=1000, height=20, background='RED')
hScroll.grid(row=1, column=0)

# Month frames
for i in range(12):
    monthFrame = tk.Frame(worksheetFrame, width=200, height=400, background='YELLOW')
    monthFrame.config(borderwidth = 2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
    monthFrame.grid(row=0, column=i, sticky=tk.W)

    # Vertical scrollbars
    vScroll = tk.Frame(monthFrame, width=20, height=400, background='GREEN')
    vScroll.grid(row=0, column=i)
```

Comment: With your Vscroll widths set at 20, and you making 12 of them, the total width of all 12 scroll bars is 240, but the frame you put them inside of has a width of 200. In fact, I see similar problems in your code with how the month frames have a width of 400 and your making 12 columns inside your workseet frame which has a width of 2000 
If I were you, I'd draw out first the kind of design you're going for, and think about the heights, widths and column placement. Also, you should use column span and row span when you want an item to span over several rows/columns, like your hScroll

Comment: `hScroll.grid()` needs to have `columspan=12` added to it, so that appears under *all* of the month frames, not just the one in column 0.

Comment: What does that first picture represent? You say you want to create 12 "blocks", but the first image has only one (or two? I'm not sure what you mean by "block").

Comment: I want to make yellow 12 blocks like in the top picture side-by-side with the green bar being on the right side for each one.

Comment: So, you just want 180 pixels of empty yellow space in each block?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to create 12 blocks inside the second frame, but when I try to create the blocks it wraps around its master frame and adds extra space at the end.

Nothing is wrapping. You have one green frame in column 0, and then the other 11 frames are in columns 1-11.

I think the thing you are missing is that you're trying to put one of the narrow green frames in column 0 of `worksheetFrame`, which is the same column that has the horizontal scrollbar. You've forced the scrollbar to be 1000 pixels wide which causes column 0 to be 1000 pixels wide. When you put a 20 pixel wide frame inside a 1000 pixel column, there's going to be a lot of unused spaced, which is what you're seeing.

> I also don't understand why I can change the hScroll width to also change the size of its master frame, example being set to 1000, but changing the width of its master frame, even increasing size does nothing.

That is again due to the fact that `grid` and `pack` by default grow or shrink a container to fit its contents. Since you add a child to `worksheetFrame` using `grid`, that frame will ignore its requested width and shrink to fit its children.

If you want a single horizontal frame that spans the width of `worksheetFrame`, you need to use `columnspan` so that it spans all of the columns:

```
hScroll.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=12)
```

Comment: I added a picture closer to what I'm going for. I want to make a frame that has a horizontal scrollbar and 12 columns with their own scrollbar. The green lines are actually supposed to be vertical scrollbars that are in a larger yellow box, although I can't get the green bars to be on the right side. I found that I can disable propagation, which sort of solves my issue.

Comment: @RenderG: disabling propagation is almost never the right solution. It will make your UI less responsive than if you left propagation on. You will be forced to do manual computations to make sure the widths are what you want, and it's easy to make a tiny change that breaks the whole UI.

Comment: Columnspan fixed the issue with spacing. What's the proper way to size things when columnspan isn't an option? vScroll is the child of monthFrame, but vScroll has a width of 20 which makes the monthFrame 20, I need monthFrame to be 200 while also keeping it's child.

Comment: @RenderG: _"What's the proper way to size things when columnspan isn't an option?"_ - that makes no sense. It's always an option when using grid. Why do you need `monthFrame` to be 200 if there's nothing in it except a 20 pixel wide frame? You can do it, but I don't see the point. If you really do need a 200 pixel wide empty frame you can turn propagation off, but I don't see the point.